# React BrowserRouter not rendering when nabber link is clicked

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am working on setting up navigation for my project using BrowerRouter and I have almost everything working except I want the components to open just itself and not everything else in my app component.....is there a way to do that? Right now everything works when I click on the navbar buttons and it opens to a new tab which I want, but all the other components in the main app also renders which I do not want. I am trying to make it so that when you press on one of the nabber link buttons it opens to a new tab with just the things in the components and not anything else in the main app component.

Here is the navbar component:

```
import React from 'react'
import './navbar.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import HOME_PAGE from './pages/HOME_PAGE.js'
import ABOUT_PAGE from './pages/ABOUT_PAGE'
import CONTACT_PAGE from './pages/CONTACT_PAGE.js'

export default function NAVBAR() {

    function hamburgerMenuClick(){
        const navbarLinks = document.querySelector('.navbar-links')
        navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
    }

    return (
        <>
        <nav className = "navbar">
            <div className = "logo">Logo</div>
            <a href="#" className = "toggle-button" onClick = {hamburgerMenuClick}>
                <span className = "bar"></span>
                <span className = "bar"></span>
                <span className = "bar"></span>
            </a>
            <div className = "navbar-links">
                <ul>
                    <Link to = "/pages/HOME_PAGE.js"><li><a >Home</a></li></Link>
                    <Link to = "/pages/ABOUT_PAGE.js"><li><a >About</a></li></Link>
                    <Link to = "/pages/CONTACT_PAGE.js"><li><a >Contact</a></li></Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <Router>
            <Route exact path = "/pages/HOME_PAGE.js" component = {HOME_PAGE}/>
            <Route exact path = "/pages/ABOUT_PAGE.js" component = {ABOUT_PAGE}/>
            <Route exact path = "/pages/CONTACT_PAGE.js" component = {CONTACT_PAGE}/>
        </Router>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **Switch**

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
          <Route exact path = "/pages/HOME_PAGE.js" component ={HOME_PAGE}/>
          <Route exact path = "/pages/ABOUT_PAGE.js" component = {ABOUT_PAGE}/>
          <Route exact path = "/pages/CONTACT_PAGE.js" component = {CONTACT_PAGE}/>
     </Switch>
 </Router>
```